# Python Decimal List

Tags: python, list, decimal

I want to make a program for reciprocal, but I get an error!

```
Input: N = 5
A(N) = 3,4,5,2,6
B(N) = 1,3,1,3,1 
Output: 2.111, 0.729, 2.040, 0.917, 2.028
```

Here's my code, which doesn't work, I don't know why:

```
n = int(input('N = '))

a = []
b = []
c = []

print('A:')
for i in range(n):
    x = float(input())
    a.append(x)

print('B:')
for i in range(n):
    y = float(input())
    b.append(y)

print('C:')
for i in range(n):
    c.append(1 / (a[i] ^ 2) + 2 / b[i])
    print(format(c[i], '.3tf'))
```

Comment: You appended your data to list a and b. But you are trying to index x and y in your last for loop. X and Y aren't iterables.

Comment: Ye, that's right.. I wrote that cause I tried to fix this. I changed it to a[i] and b[i], and it still doesn't work. Unsupported operand types for float and integer.

Comment: a and b are the right things to call. You going to have another error by using x and y. Second, I simple Google search of your error returns lots of information regarding why you might be getting this error. Have you tried doing the research ?

Comment: Yes, but I didn't find the correct answer.

Comment: Why are you using the Exclusive-OR operator, `^`? If you want to square `a[i]` then you need to do `a[i] ** 2`.

Comment: THE RIGHT ANSWER! I'm using another language (QBasic..) for competition (I'm going to republic competition soon) and I use '^' there, so  that's a mistake.. Thank you both, I fixed it now. :)

Answer (score 1):

Fixed.

```
n = int(input('N = '))

a = []
b = []
c = []

print('A:')
for i in range(n):
    x = float(input())
    a.append(x)

print('B:')
for i in range(n):
    y = float(input())
    b.append(y)

print('C:')
for i in range(n):
    c.append(1.0 / (a[i] ** 2.0) + 2.0 / b[i])
    print(format(c[i], '.3f'))
```